# Confusion related to proximal newton method

Tags: convex-optimization

I was reading this method related to proximal newton methods

http://machinelearning.wustl.edu/mlpapers/paper_files/NIPS2012_0388.pdf. I came across this page

[image]

I didn't get what this part means

$
\frac{1}{2}||y-x||^2_H
$
what does H signify here and how do I calculate $
\frac{1}{2}||y-x||^2_H
$ given x and y.

Comment: My guess is that as $H$ is a positive definite matrix, it induces a norm by means of the quadratic form $||x||_H = \sqrt{x^T H x}$. You can easily verify that this satisfies the properties of a norm. So $||\cdot||_H$ would is the norm with respect to this quadratic form.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what it is.